# What is the difference between a function and a command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to explain how my code worked when I started to talk about `print()` and was confused as to whether it was a command or a function.

I understand that you can define functions using `def x` where x is the name of the function, but what is the difference and could someone show me examples?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe "command" is a formal term for any construct in Python. You might be looking for "statement". In Python 2, `print x` is a statement, whereas in Python 3, `print` is a function.

Comment: There are no "commands" in Python. You probably confuse them with statements. A function definition `def` is a statement. A function call `print()` is a statement, too. So, `print()` is both a function call and a statement.

Comment: What about methods? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function

Comment: @cricket_007 So, what about them?

Comment: So there are functions and statements?

Comment: There are many types of statements in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html. A function call is one of them. A function definition is another.

Comment: @user82395214 Java does _not_ call functions "functions". All Java "functions" are methods.